# How to avoid printing variable in doublequote string

Tags: php, string, echo

Code snippet:

```
$str = "text";

echo "str variable contains $str";
```

This code returns:

> str variable contains text

How to return following string without closing whole echo in singlequotes? I want to somehow esape variable still using doublequotes, like this:

> str variable contains $str

Comment: I've answered the main question, but would like to ask why? Why can't you use single quotes?

Comment: I wanted to keep all strings in same quote, dont like to use 2 things (single & double quotes) for the same thing* -* bansi comment for consideration

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
echo "str variable contains \$str";
```

Comment: or `echo 'str variable contains $str';`

Comment: @Nadh I think from the question he doesn't want to enclose with single quotes

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automate this, use `str_replace()`.

```
$str = "text";
$text = "str variable contains $str";
$text = str_replace('$', '\$', $text);
echo $text;
```